Anime/cartoon about a futuristic world where everything runs on a type of crystal that explodes when exposed to the sun for too long
It's some kind of old anime about a futuristic world where human-created vehicles can fly, all that sci-fi stuff. The thing is, they run on some type of blue crystal or rock, which I don't fully remember.
The problem with this crystal/rock is that when exposed to the sun, it will turn red, boil up the liquid around it, and explode. I remember in one scene, a little girl was riding a bike, and the crystal/rock got exposed to the sun and it immediately turned red.

My brain is going toward the Shizuma Drive from Giant Robo, but I don't think sunlight was involved.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And was it a movie or a series?

I think I was like 10 I'm 21 now so I guess 11 years ago 2013 and it was a series
